# Alert in PhantomJS Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, phantomjs

I using Python 3 and PhantomJS. I want get alert text, but when I compile my project I have errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dante/Documents/GitHub/ProjectHeisenberg/BioInfoRNA/Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "C:/Users/Dante/Documents/GitHub/ProjectHeisenberg/BioInfoRNA/Main.py", line 63, in Main
    print(alert.text)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line 65, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:50844","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/alert_text","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"alert_text","directory":"/","path":"/alert_text","relative":"/alert_text","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/alert_text","queryKey":{},"chunks":["alert_text"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/24c37130-3103-11e6-bf6e-074d3d3fe80d/alert_text"}
```

and this is my code fragment:

```
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
browser.switch_to_alert()
print(alert.text)
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: What `PhantomJS` version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe Version: 2.1.1

Comment: Okay, what if you upgrade `selenium` package to the latest version? `pip3 install --upgrade selenium`

Comment: I have actual version of selenium

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: doesn't fix the problem for me